# Apache Camel - Jetty component queue requests with same parameters from different browser tabs

Tags: jetty, apache-camel

camel-jetty 2.12.1

```
<c:route>
    <c:from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8055/ws/consulta" />
    <c:log message="${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" />
    <c:delay>
        <c:constant>10000</c:constant>
    </c:delay>
</c:route>
```

---

If I open two tabs in the browser and execute:

```
[tab1] http://localhost:8055/ws/consulta?param=param1
[tab2] http://localhost:8055/ws/consulta?param=param1
```

Camel is **not able** to process them in parallel.

---

But if I the tabs have diferent parameters:

```
[tab1] http://localhost:8055/ws/consulta?param=param1
[tab2] http://localhost:8055/ws/consulta?param=param2
```

Camel is **able** to process them concurrently.

---

If I open just one tab and execute:

```
[tab1] http://localhost:8055/ws/consulta?param=param1
[tab1] http://localhost:8055/ws/consulta?param=param1
```

Camel is **able** to process them concurrently.

---

**It is a bug?**

Answer (score 0):

No its not a bug. Its likely your browser preventing duplicate "clicks.

If you have two terminals and use curl or some command line tool, then they are sent concurrently.

For example I can open two shells and type

```
curl http://localhost:8055/ws/consulta?param=param1
```

And have the requests come in (well it took a 2 sec for me to send the 2nd)

```
2013-10-16 17:17:04,773 [tp2043068409-12] INFO  route1                         - 2013-10-16 17:17:04
2013-10-16 17:17:06,069 [tp2043068409-14] INFO  route1                         - 2013-10-16 17:17:06
```